# How to route to a static folder in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

I have a folder I've placed in the /public folder in my Laravel site. The path is:

```
/public/test
```

the "test" folder has a file called index.html that is just a static resource I want to load from the public folder (I don't want to create a view for this within the framework--too much to explain).

I've made a route like this:

```
Route::get('/test', function() {
  return File::get(public_path() . '/test/index.html');
});
```

I'm not able to get this to work. I just get an error from Chrome saying this page has a redirect loop.

I can access it this way:

```
http://www.example.com/test/index.html
```

But I can't use the .html extension anywhere. The file must be visible as:

```
http://www.example.com/test/
```

How can I serve a single HTML page from the Laravel public folder without having to use the .html extension?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

used to face this problem before, as a dirty little trick, you may rename the test folder to something else then update

```
return File::get(public_path() . '/to new folder name/index.html');
```

the key is no conflict between your route url with your folder in public

Comment: This worked. As you said, the key is making sure your route path and the path (folder) in the public directory each have different names.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Btw how did you manage assets inside test directory?

Answer (score 4):

For a static file, I think you're wasting resources serving it through Laravel.

There have been some bugs in the past creating infinite redirects when trying to access files/folders within `public`, but I think the latest .htaccess that comes with Laravel has these resolved (on Apache, at least). It looks like this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

It says 'If the request is not for an existing folder, strip the trailing slash if there is one. If the request is not for an existing folder or for an existing file, load Laravel's index.php'

I then added a .htaccess file within the subdirectory to ensure that the DirectoryIndex is set so that index.html will be loaded by default on a request for a directory.

Comment: A use case is: protecting the static content from unauthenticated users.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
return Redirect::to('/test/index');
```

Either at the function at your routes file or inside a controller.

Comment: That didn't work. I still get the redirect loop error.