# Angular2 + Laravel5 - how to correct organize routing between them?

Tags: typescript, laravel-5.1, angular, laravel-5

I play with L5 and A2.

I have 2 routes for L5: '/' (base) and '/edit'.
I have 2 routes for A2: '/' (base) and '/edit' (name: 'Edit');

When i will load `blablabla.com` page, doing some stuff - Angular2 will redirecting me by '/edit' Angular2 route on `blablabla.com/edit` url. At this A2 route - some A2 component will loaded.

But, when i stay on `blablabla.com/edit` url, if i reload page - on url `blablabla.com/edit` running Laravel5 route '/edit' with 404 error.

At this situation how i can connect L5 route '/edit' with A2 route '/edit'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact, it's normal that you have a 404 error when refreshing your application since the actual address within the browser is updating (and without # / hashbang approach). By default, HTML5 history is used for reusing in Angular2.

If you want not having a 404 error, you need to update your server to serve the `index.html` file for each route path you defined.

If you want to switch to the HashBang approach, you need to use this configuration:

```
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {provide} from 'angular2/core';
import {ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/router';
import {LocationStrategy, Location, HashLocationStrategy } from 'angular2/router'; 

import {MyApp} from './myapp';

bootstrap(MyApp, [
  ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
  provide(LocationStrategy, {useClass: HashLocationStrategy}
]);
```

In this case, when you refresh the page, it will be displayed again (but you will have a `#` in your address).

This link could help you as well: [When I refresh my website I get a 404. This is with Angular2 and firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34415725/when-i-refresh-my-website-i-get-a-404-this-is-with-angular2-and-firebase/).

Regarding Lavarel, you need to configure redirects: `Redirect::to($route)` for each elements of your Angular2 routes.

These links could help you:

- https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/responses#redirecting-named-routes
- [How to route to a static folder in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29217937/how-to-route-to-a-static-folder-in-laravel)

Hope it helps you,
Thierry