# Can I arrive Laravel with static HTML pages?

Tags: php, html, laravel

I made contact page with Laravel.

On the other hand, They made static page with HTML/CSS

I think we have 2 solutions.

One way, Absorb static page in Laravel like this.

```
(Now)

static/
  index.html
  index.css
  images/
    aa.jpg

public/
  css/
    contact.css
  images/
    contact/
      bb.jpg
resources/
  views/
    contact/
      index.blade.php

(Absorb to Laravel)

public/
  css/
    index.css
    contact.css
  images/
    aa.jpg
    contact/
      bb.jpg
resources/
  views/
    index.blade.php
    contact/
      index.blade.php
```

It seems simple and easy.
But this way must merge all files by me, It is so bother to do.

And other way, That made contact page WITHOUT laravel, just use PHP.

```
static/
  index.html
  index.css
  contact/
    index.php
    contact.css
    images/
      bb.jpg
  images/
    aa.jpg
```

It seems easy to understand Directory structure.
But I dont made that. So it take long time to made again.

So, I wish to do other solutions like this.

```
static/
  index.html
  index.css
  contact/ --> symbolic link
  images/
    aa.jpg

contact/
  public/
    css/
      contact.css
    images/
      contact/
        bb.jpg
  resources/
    views/
      contact/
        index.blade.php
```

Can I do this?

Comment: i think u could use resources/ views/contact/index.blade.php and for style or scripts files resources/assets/css/contact.css or resources/assets/images/bb.jpg ,but in that case you have to remove public from url (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39057011/how-to-run-laravel-from-root-directory-not-from-public/39060960#39060960)

Comment: one thing see ur images are many...i think its not bettr way to have many  images folder...u can organise it like assets /your css folder(where all css files) or img folder (where sll img) or js folder (where all js files)...then inside of css/js/img u can add more folder ..but css folder means there is only css files ...its bettr for developrs to understand efficiently according to my opinion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved with this issue. Thanks everyone.
It's way of absorb to Laravel.

[How to route to a static folder in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29217937/how-to-route-to-a-static-folder-in-laravel)